# How to install R package "copula" on RHEL7?

Tags: r, rhel7, rstudio-server, jupyterhub

We have been trying to install "copula" package on `R` but it fails with the following error message:

`ERROR: dependency ‘gsl’ is not available for package ‘copula’`

1. After installing GSL (GNU Scientific Linux), it kept complaining but this time with the following error:

```
** package ‘gsl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gsl-config... no
configure: error: gsl-config not found, is GSL installed? <<-----------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gsl’
* removing ‘/opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.3/lib64/R/library/gsl’
ERROR: dependency ‘gsl’ is not available for package ‘copula’
* removing ‘/opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.3/lib64/R/library/copula’
```

2. We have also installed `gsl-devel` (`yum install gsl-devel`); unsuccessfully though.
3. Manually installed GSL:

- `wget https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/gnu/gsl/gsl-latest.tar.gz`
- `tar xfz gsl-latest.tar.gz`
- `./configure && make && make install`

4. Back to `R`, tried to install `copula` again, unsuccessfully, but with a different error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gsl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.3/lib64/R/library/gsl/libs/gsl.so':
  libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to install GSL and make `libgsl.so.25` available to `copula`?

Thanks.

Comment: does this have anything to do with jupyterhub?

Comment: Hello Michael, it does, indeed. We are using RStudio on Jupyterhub.

Comment: but it looks like the issue is purely related to using the RStudio package manager on linux - not an issue related to jupyterhub itself.

Answer (score 1):

We have tried the following workaround which solved the issue:

1. Set the following environment variables before installing `copula`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

2. Install `copula` via `R`:

```
> install.packages("copula")
```

3. Manually copy `libgsl.so.25` to `/usr/lib64`

```
[root@worksation ~]# ldd /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.3/lib64/R/library/gsl/libs/gsl.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc9b838000)
        libgsl.so.25 => not found  <<<<------------- MISSING 
        libgslcblas.so.0 => /lib64/libgslcblas.so.0 (0x00007fd237b72000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd237870000)
        libR.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007fd2371f2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd236e25000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd237fcd000)
        libRblas.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so (0x00007fd234931000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fd23460f000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fd2343d3000)
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fd23418d000)
        libtre.so.5 => /lib64/libtre.so.5 (0x00007fd233f7d000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fd233d06000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fd233aa4000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fd23387e000)
        libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007fd23366e000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd233458000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd233250000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd23304c000)
        libicuuc.so.50 => /lib64/libicuuc.so.50 (0x00007fd232cd3000)
        libicui18n.so.50 => /lib64/libicui18n.so.50 (0x00007fd2328d4000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fd2326ae000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd232498000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd23227c000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fd232052000)
        libicudata.so.50 => /lib64/libicudata.so.50 (0x00007fd230a80000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd230779000)
```

- To find libgsl.so.25:

```
[root@workstation /usr/lib64]# find / -name libgsl.so.25 2>/dev/null
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.so.25
/root/gsl-2.7/.libs/libgsl.so.25
```

- Then:

```
cp -p /usr/local/lib/libgsl.so.25 /usr/lib64/
```

There's surely a different approach to resolve this issue but this one worked fine for us. Thanks.